# Laplace equation, Taylor expansion

Tags: partial-differential-equations, taylor-expansion

I couldn't find it anywhere, so I decided to write my question here:

I have problems solving this equation:

$$u_{xx} + u_{yy} = 4,$$

subjected to the conditions

$$u(x,x)=2x^2, \quad u_x(x,x)=2x$$

I've solved a similar problem, only there the initial conditions were on $u(0,y)$ and $u_x(0,y)$ and I used Taylor's expansion there:

$$u(x,y)= u(x_0,y) + u_x(x_0, y)(x-x_0)+ \frac{1}{2} u_{xx}(x_0, y)(x-x_0)^2 + ...$$

and there I could plug $x_0 = 0$.

Could you tell me how to use it here?

Comment: Why not to use the method of characteristics?

Comment: I know I could use method of characteristics here, but I wanted to try Taylor's expansion. Could you tell me if, according to the equations above, $u_{xx}(x,x)=2$?

Comment: Hi @Hagrid! Answering your question, **no**, it's not true, in general. Try to think in a more simple example where you specify the value of the function and of its derivative in the boundary. Must there be any relation between them and between the 2nd derivative in the boundary? (A graph would help)

Comment: Ok, for example for $u(x,y)=2xy$, we have $u_x(x,y)=2y, \ u_x(x,x)=2x, \ \ u_{xx}(x,y)=0$. So I see I made a mistake. Could you tell me how to compute it? From the main equation we know that $u_{xx}=4-u_{yy}$. But where to get $u_{yy}$ from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the initial condition is a quadratic polynomial, and Laplacian is constant, we should expect to find $u$ as a quadratic polynomial. That is, look for $u$ in the form
$$u(x,y)=Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2$$
The PDE gives $A+C=2$, the value of $u(x,x)$ gives $A+B+C=2$, and the value of $u_x(x,x)$ gives $2A+B=2$. Solve for $A,B,C$ and you are done.